# Search is not working in individual site's winter bash leaderboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, winter-bash-2021, winterbash-leaderboard

In the individual site's leaderboard, there is a search box with a placeholder "Type to find users".
When typing any user's name and hitting enter, there is no matched data is returned.

Stack Overflow leaderboard URL: https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com

Screenshot for reference:

[image: user search is not working]

---

**UPDATE:** Actually the searched results are displayed at the bottom of the page. It means the top section is not hidden correctly, and it looks like no searched result is displayed.

[image: GIF for search issue]

Comment: There should be an element with `.leaders` class - that's what the JS tries to hide. Running `$('.search-results').prev().addClass('leaders')` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This bug has been fixed and now able to see the correct results.

**GIF for reference:**
[image: Search is working]